# Работа с MySQL, вставка значений

Tags: mysql, запись

```html
<?php

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mydb_user', 'admin123', 'my_db');

mysqli_query (SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

$db = mysqli_select_db ("my_db");


if(!connection || !$db)

{
    exit(mysqli_error());
}


$result = mysqli_query("SELECT*FROM News");

mysqli_close();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo $row('title');
}
?>
```

Требуется записать в таблицу значение, считать из бд запись, вывести на экран, как это сделать?

Comment: У вас есть идея как добится желаемого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас пропущено кавычки, замените у себя на это:
`mysqli_query ("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");`

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы добавить какое-то значение в базу нужно сформировать запрос, например для вставки используем:

```
$query_insert = 'INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)';

mysqli_query($query_insert);
```

для выборки

```
$query_select = 'SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name';

mysqli_query($query_select);
```

а дальше уже я думаю ви разберетесь)